# Calling background service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to call a push notification background service from BroadcastReceiver class, but my application crashes.  The code is given below:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static int count=1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,NotifyService.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(myIntent);  
    }
}
```

The manifest entry:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".NotifyService">
</service>
```

The error:

```
05-24 15:17:00.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(424): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.alarm/com.android.alarm.NotifyService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

When I call this service through an Activity it's working, but my goal is to call this service from a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AlarmReceiver` is calling `startActivity()`, not `startService()`. You start services with `startService()`; you start activities with `startActivity()`.

Also, services do not need (or use, AFAIK) `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to use C2DM for push notification in Android......May this will be your solution......